# Is it possible to launch an interactive elixir shell and call a function immediately?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

In elixir you can use the `iex` shell with the context of your application with the following command...

```
iex -S mix
```

This command is super handy and lets us use an application functions in the interactive shell.

I am wondering if it is possible to start the interactive shell with arguments, or if it is possible to have your application call some functions before the user can interact with the shell.

For example, let's say I have an application called `MyApp` and I start it with `iex -S mix`. Instead of having to manually enter commands into the shell, e.g.

```elixir
iex()> import MyApp.Module

iex()> alias MyApp.Module.OtheName

iex()> value = OtherName.function(1234)
```

there would be a way to have this happen automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a file `.iex.exs` in your application directory with the code to run at startup. From the man page of `iex`:

> After iex starts, it seeks the file .iex.exs and, in a case of
>   success, executes the code from the file in the context of the shell.
>   At first the search starts in the current working directory, then, if
>   necessary, it continues in the home directory.

But beware that if you put application specific code in this file, it will only run correct if you execute `iex -S mix`, but not when you execute just `iex`.

Comment: Interesting that this behaves differently to just passing a script name via `iex scripts.exs`. Passing the script name doesn't preserve assigned variables, but `.iex.exs` does. You can also customise the filename with `--dot-iex` (strange option name).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that `--dot-iex` option. Very useful.